# How to work with javascript functions in an anonymous function in the browser console?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, web-console

I've found an interesting method of defining functions:

```
! function() {
  function myFunction() {
    return returnValue;
  }
}();
```

However, this function can not be called directly from the browser console, how could I achieve it?

Comment: It's anonymous -- you can't. If you need to call it whenever, you need to define it.

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/#iife - an interesting read about IIFEs

Comment: you need to assign its reference to a variable first.

Comment: You can't call it because it's been scoped to your outer function.  That's one reason why you do this, to stop the pollution of higher levels with functions/variables they don't need to know about.  This really sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what do you want to actually achieve?

Comment: Anonymous functions are nameless, so if you do not assign them to a var, they will execute and will not have a handle to them.  They are great for scope control and one off executions.  Otherwise you have to return sometime and assign it to a var handle or something similar.

Comment: That was just an academical question – I saw an app using this method and wanted to play with it and learn how it works, which is explained in the Serban's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) wrapped around your function.

I would suggest using this approach for the code that you've written:

```
!function() {
  function myFunction() {
    return 'hello';
  }

  window['myFunction'] = myFunction;
}();
```

Now call `myFunction` in the console.
Previously `myFunction` was hidden inside your IIFE and was not exposed as a global.